# Filling modal content using PHP and AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want the user to be able to click on a table, and depending on the row they click on - it would fill the modal with content relating to that row (a MYSQL query), and open the modal.

I've attempted to do this like the following:
- Load table content
- Listen to when table is clicked on using jQuery
- Use AJAX to post to the PHP file with the clicked on row's information
- Execute MYSQL query using the row info
- Filling the modal with the gathered content
- Opening the modal

The problem I've encountered is that because it's a MYSQL statement and the function is non-blocking, the variables haven't been declared by the time the modal's started to open. Web programming isn't exactly my forte, so I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

**jQuery/AJAX**

```
$('#alerts tbody').delegate('tr', 'click', function() {
  var id = $('td:eq(0)', this).text(); // Gets the ID of the row

  // PHP Method (below)


  // Passes ID through to PHP
  $.ajax({
    url: "alerts.php",
    method: "GET",
    data: {id: ID},
    async: true,
    done: function() {
        loadModalFunction();
    }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
  if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    // MYSQL Query
    // Sets global variables    
  }
?>
```

**Modal**

```
$('#info').find('.modal-title').text("Information (#" + id + ")");
$('#info').find('#modal-body-content').text("<?php echo $GLOBALS['content'];?>");
```

I know that the getting passing of the ID and getting of the content works, but the content isn't passed to the ID as the modal is loaded before the script initialises the global variables.

Comment: Without code, we cannot help. Logic sounds fine.

Comment: You should post some code, I have the setup you're talking about up and working. I do it by first running a function onclick, the function fills the modal with the contents of a php file using jQuery, and then the modal is manually toggled. But then again you could also do this using the modal events in bootstrap, but then the modal might show empty and fill up afterwards.

Comment: @Novocaine There's the code!

Comment: @aron9forever Added some code - are you using a separate PHP file to load the content? Right now I've got the PHP in the same file as the actual webpage.

Comment: Wow, you got it really, really wrong. This thing `$('#info').find('#modal-body-content').text("<?php echo $GLOBALS['content'];?>");` , the PHP part to be specific, is only ran when you load the page. PHP is loaded before you even see the webpage. You need to get the contents in another way

Comment: @aron9forever Oh okay - how else would you propose editing/setting the modal?

Comment: `PHP` is server side - meaning it's ran *before* the web page loads, and Javascript is `client side` - meaning it's ran *after* the web page is loaded. The two are only ever able to communicate through ajax.

Comment: @OliverQueen Okay, so how else would I load content after the web page has been loaded from a MYSQL query?

Comment: The cycle of your request should look something like this: **PHP** -> **Javascript** -> **PHP**

Comment: In other words, the request will initiate the php, then your javascript will make an ajax call to an external PHP file, and then your javascript will handle the data from there

Comment: did you notice you get the `id` as `id` and pass it to ajax as `ID`.

Comment: @OliverQueen How would I make a Javascript call from PHP if the webpage has already been loaded?

Comment: @FrayneKonok Yeah I only typed out the code that was necessary (and made a mistake),  I can assure you the passing of the ID works properly in the actual file :)

Comment: You cannot call Javascript from PHP

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding the "**PHP -> Javascript**" part then?

Comment: So that was just a representation of how the request occurs. The order of operations, if you will

Comment: I'll post some code as an answer

Comment: and @OliverQueen of course you can, `echo "<script>alert(1)</script>";`

Comment: @OliverQueen Okay gotcha, but the PHP is non-blocking so it's important that the Javascript is only initiated after the PHP query has been made - so how would I go about making the Javascript only call once the query is complete?

Comment: @aron9forever - You can **NEVER** call Javascript in PHP. **EVER**. Period.

Comment: @OliverQueen I literally just posted an example of calling javascript using PHP. If I load another PHP file into my loaded page using jQuery, and that PHP file outputs javascript, are you saying the javascript will not execute? Since I have a website that sort of relies on doing that and seems to work.

Comment: @OliverQueen I'm assuming he means you can output Javascript to the HTML using PHP which will be called at runtime, which is effectively the same as calling Javascript in that situation.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what we are talking about, @aron9forever . A javascript function can never be called in PHP and vice versa. They do not talk. They can *invoke* eachother, however

Comment: @OliverQueen you're right, but you're not being helpful. You're just saying "you can't do that" because we said "call" instead of "invoke" which is just a debate over terminology, completely irrelevant to the topic. Your comments give the impression that it's impossible to do when it's not.

Comment: Then you must not have read my comments very well. I very clearly say it is **NOT** possible.

Comment: And how is that good for this when clearly the end result ***is*** possible, the only difference being the words used to describe the method? Put yourself in OPs shoes and read your comments, do you think he should leave with the impression that it's impossible for javascript to interact with php? Whether it's possible or not is only defined by your interpretation of "interaction" which is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah, it's impossible for PHP to call javascript and vice versa. Yeah, it's possible to invoke PHP via javascript and vice versa. NO, it's not impossible to accomplish whatever OP wants do to. Why do you keep repeating "it's not possible" when it is, the only difference is the way you say it?

Comment: They do not interact ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, here's my implementation on this issue, it will be a bit simpler to just provide the basics and let you edit your own code accordingly.

First of all my entire modal content is a div with an id, `<div id="modalcontent"> </div>`

Then, suppose this button should open and populate my modal with data

```
<a href="#" onclick="openModal()">Open</a>
```

openModal() will look something like this

```
$.post("alerts.php", {
    id: ID
}, function(data) {//data will contain whatever alerts.php prints
document.getElementById("modalcontent").innerHTML = data;//insert data into modal
$('#my-modal').modal('toggle');//open modal
});
```

Again, there are many ways to do this. There are better ways to do this. But you should understand how something like this works, you can only get the output of the PHP file in javascript and edit your contents with javascript. You can get your data from another PHP script, which will be executed by javascript whenever you need it, but the PHP script itself can not modify the contents of your already loaded page.

Using this code and assuming alerts.php will `echo "you have a notification";`, `<div id="modalcontent"> </div>` will change to `<div id="modalcontent">you have a notification</div>` and then the modal will be toggled. This method also ensures the modal is only opened **after** the data is fetched so it's impossible for the modal to open without the data inside.