# How to transfer JQuery variable into PHP variable in a modal window without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to this client variable to server variable transfer process.

Essentially I have a Google maps api function and have a marker on a map to represent a username in a users table (MySQL) of my PHP web app. When I double click on that map marker my Jquery function is popping up a modal and I am able to get the username in an id/name element (chosenUser) in a . However, I now need to be able to access this value in a PHP variable ($chosenUser) without any "submit" or page refresh, so that I can invoke my PHP function - getUserChannelID($chosenUser), and continue with the rest of the logic.

My disconnect is the ability to be able to access that value coming through on the id/name as #chosenUser and transfer it to a PHP variable $chosenUser without a "submit" or page refresh. All the code below is on the same page.

I am reading about the use of AJAX to do this in SF posts but since I quite the infant with AJAX I am getting confused on how exactly this can be done on the same page without a form "submit" or page refresh.

Can you please help correcting the code below so that I can get that value in #chosenUser to the PHP variable $chosenUser?

Here's my code all in the same PHP file.

```
<?php
require_once("classes/autoload.php");
$db = new Database();
....

?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 0 auto;">            
    <div style="height: 100%; position: relative; top:30px;">
            <div id="map" style="height: 100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="showChannel" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Channel Preview</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div>
                       <input type="hidden"  id="chosenUser" name="chosenUser" value="">        
<!-- This is where I need help. How do I transfer that value I am getting for "chosenUser" above into the PHP variable $chosenUser - ideally the code in the next line would need to be executed -->
                       <?php $channelId = $db->getUserChannelID($chosenUser); ?>
                       .....
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.20&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="multiple_marker/oms.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var mapMarkers = [];
var infowindow = null;
var infowindowOpen;
var map, oms;
var gm = google.maps;
var markerIcons = new Array();
var gmarkers = [];

function getCoords() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "markers.php",  // this markers.php provides the value of "Locations" array used below
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            foo: "bar"
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (returnedData) {

            console.log(returnedData);
            if(!spiderify)
                moveMarkerMap(returnedData);
            //window.setInterval(getCoords, 10000);
            window.setTimeout(getCoords, 2000);
        }
    });
}

function MarkerMap(json) {
    var iconBase;
    oms.addListener('click', function (marker) {
        console.log('clicked');
    });

    if ((json.Locations.length > 0)) {
        for (i = 0; i < json.Locations.length; i++) {
            var location = json.Locations[i];
            var username = location.username; // I am getting the value of username here
            var myLatlng = new gm.LatLng(location.Lat, location.Long);
            var marker = new gm.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    username: username,
                });
            var infowindow = new gm.InfoWindow();
            var div = document.createElement('DIV');

            gm.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', (function (marker, div, infowindow) {
                    return function () {
                        $('#showChannel').modal('show');

                        $('#chosenUser').val(marker.username); //passing the value of marker.username to the modal input id/name="chosenUser"
                    };
                })(marker, div, infowindow));

                gmarkers[id] = marker;
            }
        }
        window.map = map;
        window.oms = omg;
    }
    gm.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: check out my answer here, it has a pretty detailed explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656972/filling-modal-content-using-php-and-ajax/35657856#35657856. You're mostly interested in the second part of the answer, related to communication between js and php.

Comment: @aron9forever, thank you for your link. I apologize that I am unable to figure out from your answer in that link, how I can get the value of the "id/name" - chosenUser can be transferred over to the $chosenUser PHP variable. Would you be so kind to explain a little more? I am still very green in this type of coding. My modal is coming up just fine, just that transfer of value is not happening

Comment: I'll write a more detailed answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't exactly communicate between PHP and JS in the way you're thinking of. PHP is executed while the page is loading, before any content is displayed, before any javascript is even sent to the client, so it's impossible to do it as you wish.

What you can do is call a PHP script once the page is finished loading, using javascript. You can do this whenever you like, using a delay loop, when clicking a button, any way you can call your javascript function. That way you can send information from javascript to PHP, and when the PHP script finishes running it can report back information to javascript.

You want a variable from js in PHP, there are multiple ways of doing this, such as POST or GET requests. I'll post an example using POST, which is the same thing you'd use to send a form. You'll need to include jQuery for this to work.

JS

```
var myVar = "my info";
var myVar2 = "my other info";
$.post("myscript.php", {
info1: myVar,
info2: myVar2
}, function(answer) {
// answer will contain whatever the PHP script printed
// in this example answer will be "success"
alert(answer);
} );
```

PHP

```
$var1 = $_POST['info1'];
$var2 = $_POST['info2'];
if(!empty($var1) && !empty($var2))
{
    echo "success";
}
```

It's up to you to implement it now.

Comment: Thanks and this makes a lot of sense now. I tried with that PHP script to be in the same myscript.php file, so that I can get the value of $var1 available in the modal in myscript.php but I am not getting any values in $var1.         $.post("myscript.php", { info1: info1 },
  function(data) {
   $("#message").fadeIn(); });

Comment: Don't try to implement it in your code straight away. Try to write a simple script first, just to see how it works. You need to separate your main PHP/HTML page, which contains the modal, the js and everything else, and `myscript.php` which will only do one task, that is get the data you pass from js, process it and then return the information to javascript.

Comment: To give a practical example, I have a page that uses this, called `myservices.php`. The page contains a lot of forms and information that control several linux applications. On that page I also have two javascript buttons that call `start.php` and `stop.php`, passing information about the targeted app to the PHP scripts, which either start or kill the process, and then print out "success" or "failed". I gave this example so you can understand that you need lots of small scripts that only do one task for this, calling the same page you're on would be pretty wasteful.

Comment: Thanks and yes, I was able to get the second PHP file - myscript.php to be triggered following your advice from my main index.php file where the modal exists. However how do I get the value back from myscript.php to the modal inside index.php that triggered that JS in the first place, without refreshing index.php? I think I am very close to the solution - just the last piece is missing.

Comment: @JohnG that part is explained in the answer I posted in the first link I gave you, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656972/filling-modal-content-using-php-and-ajax/35657856#35657856.

Comment: Ok @aron9forever, I was able to make it work - thank you very much for your help - I really appreciate it