# how to show a php page in a modal

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

I was wondering if it is possible to catch a whole php page in a modal. 
It is about this situation:
I have now an anchor which leads me to the page like this:

```
<a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $article['articleId']; ?>"><?php echo $article['title']; ?></a>
```

How can i put the whole content of, lets say, the page `post.php?id=1` in a modal like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

   <!-- Modal content-->
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>HERE SHOULD COME THE CONTENT OP THE PHP FILE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

in `post.php`; these are the lines which parse the content:

```
<h3> <?php echo $article['title']; ?> </h3>
<p class="content article-content"> <?php echo nl2br($article['content']); ?> </p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filling modal content using PHP and AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656972/filling-modal-content-using-php-and-ajax)

Comment: What is in your post.php file ?..I think you should use AJAX for this.

Comment: updated my post; content of `post.php`

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$('#modal-body').load('/your/url/here', {var1: val1, var2: val2}, function(){
    // show your modal here
});
```

See here for more info https://api.jquery.com/load/